# Is it true that primes of the form $5 + 6k$ exceed primes of the form $7 + 6k$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics

I ran a little computational experiment where I computed the number of primes of the form $5 + 6k \leq n$ and $7 + 6k \leq n$, and noticed that as $n$ grew in size,  primes of the form $5 + 6k$ started to exceed those of the form $7 + 6k$. Is this true? Do primes of the form $7 + 6k$ cross back over at large values of $n$?

Some results:

```
n = 10^1 -> delta =     0
n = 10^2 -> delta =    +1
n = 10^3 -> delta =    +6
n = 10^4 -> delta =    +5
n = 10^5 -> delta =   +22
n = 10^6 -> delta =   +34
n = 10^7 -> delta =  +189
n = 10^8 -> delta =  +419
n = 10^9 -> delta = +2106
```

The program I used to compute the above:

```
/**
 * primes.c
 * build:   gcc -O3 primes.c
 * run:     ./a.out <N>
 */

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void prime_pi(long n)
{
    uint8_t* sieve = calloc((n + 1) / 2, sizeof(uint8_t));
    assert(sieve != NULL);

    for (long i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        if (sieve[i / 2] == 0)
        {
            for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += 2 * i)
            {
                sieve[j / 2] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    long count_of_5_plus_6k = 0;
    long count_of_7_plus_6k = 0;

    for (long i = 5; i <= n; i += 6)
    {
        if (sieve[i / 2] == 0)
        {
            count_of_5_plus_6k++;
        }
    }

    for (long i = 7; i <= n; i += 6)
    {
        if (sieve[i / 2] == 0)
        {
            count_of_7_plus_6k++;
        }
    }

    printf("|5 + 6k| = %ld\n", count_of_5_plus_6k);
    printf("|7 + 6k| = %ld\n", count_of_7_plus_6k);

    printf("delta = %ld\n", count_of_5_plus_6k - count_of_7_plus_6k);

    free(sieve);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    long n = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    prime_pi(n);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit 0**: Add results.

**Edit 1**: Fixed inaccuracies in numbers and add program used to compute results.

**Edit 2**: Change `6i` in code to `6k`.

Comment: This is not true. This would contradict Dirichlet’s theorem... kind of. Dirichlet’s theorem states that there would be infinitely many primes in both those forms (called “residue classes” if you want to be technical.) The thing is, the theorem was proved by showing that all residue classes have equal proportions of primes in them.

Comment: [Suggested reading](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408319.pdf):  " There are arbitrarily large values of $x$ for which there
are more primes of the form $3n+ 1$ up to $x$ than primes of the form $3n+ 2$...first ... at
$x = 608,981,813,029.$"

Comment: @BarryCipra
I mean the following: Let $f(n)$ be the number of primes of the form $5 + 6i$ that are $\leq n$. Let $g(n)$ be the number of primes of the form $7 + 6i$ that are $\leq n$. Then, $f(n) - g(n) \rightarrow + \infty$ as $n \rightarrow + \infty$.

Comment: Please clarify:  is $i^2=-1$ (@BarryCipra suggested $5+6i$ is complex), or $i\in\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner
No, $i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. I changed $i$ to $k$ to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Wouldn’t delta$=0$ for $n=10$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner
You're absolutely right! Let me double check my numbers.

Comment: @asfeynman:  your numbers now agree with those on page 5 of the reference I cited (note:  that reference counted $2$, so your counts differ by $1$)

Comment: @asfeynman, sorry about the "complex" question, that was a brain fart on my part. (I saw the "$i$," assumed you were looking at Gaussian primes, and didn't notice that $5+6i$ and $7+6i$ would then be two *numbers*, not two sequences of numbers. The change from "$i$" to "$k$" helps.) And thanks for adding the synopsis of your computations.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularPrimeCountingFunction.html

Comment: @BarryCipra that's okay :)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner it's strange that they would count 2.

Comment: @asfeynman:  they were counting primes of the form $2+3k$ vs. $1+3k$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, understood. That makes more sense.

Comment: same with the above link by Roddy MacPhee

Comment: I'm curious:  how long did your experiment take to run?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Computing the difference for $n = 10^9$ takes approximately 4 seconds on my machine. Everything combined takes less than 5 seconds.

Comment: so then you should be able to demonstrate the cross-over in less than an hour, or is storage space a constraint?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm not sure I understand. Do you know that it crosses over at some point?

Comment: yes, that was my answer (below) to your question

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, I see. Unfortunately, my machine runs out of memory for $n > 10^{10}$. I would have to reimplement the sieve in a segmented form, so I will trust the paper for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's some terminology we should be careful about. It's not correct to write that "primes of the form $5+6k$ exceed primes of the form $7+6k$" because the cardinality of the set of primes $5+6k$ is equal to the cardinality of the set of primes $7+6k$—these are both countably infinite sets, per Dirichlet's theorem. Furthermore, a strengthening of Dirichlet's theorem states that for any coprime $a,b$, the set of primes congruent to $a$ modulo $b$ has [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Definition) $\frac{1}{\phi(b)}$, so in an asymptotic sense primes $5 \ \text{mod} \ 6$ are roughly around as prevalent as primes $7 \ \text{mod} \ 6$.

Nevertheless, the result is only asymptotic, so it does not paint the whole picture. The question which I believe you want to ask is the following, and it is indeed an interesting one.

> For any coprime $(a,b)$, we denote by $\mathcal{P}(a,b,x)$ the number of primes at most $x$ which are congruent to $a \ \text{mod} \ b$.
>
> Now, let us fix $N$ and let $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...,a_{\phi(N)}$ be a [reduced residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system) modulo $N$. Then must it be the case that for any permutation $\pi \in S_{\phi(N)}$ that there are arbitrarily large $x$ such that $\mathcal{P}(a_{\pi(1)}, N, x) \leq \mathcal{P}(a_{\pi(2)}, N, x) \leq \mathcal{P}(a_{\pi(3)}, N, x) \leq ... \leq \mathcal{P}(a_{\pi(\phi(N))}, N, x)$?

This is called the *Shanks–Renyi race problem* and I believe it is still open. Some weaker results have been proven assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis, and it's possible that these weaker results may be sufficient to solve your problem, although the literature is pretty overwhelming.

I will also add that computational results are basically irrelevant here, because the "switches" might occur at incredibly large $x$, beyond the range of hardware. See [Skewes Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number). [Edit: this last sentence here may be incorrect, as the other answer indicates that a computational solution has been found for your specific problem. Nonetheless, *in general*, you cannot always rely on computers for such problems].

Comment: What is $\phi(b)$ defined to be? I couldn't find it in the linked wikipedia article. Perhaps the Euler totient function?

Comment: @asfeynman Yes, the Euler totient function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to [Bays and Hudson, Math. Comp. 32:571, 
1978](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-142/S0025-5718-1978-0476616-X/S0025-5718-1978-0476616-X.pdf),

the number of primes up to $n$ of the form $3k+1$ exceeds

the number of primes up to $n$ of the form $3k+2$

when $n= 608,981,813,029$.